# Populating div and sub-div elements with external content

Tags: jquery, html, css, automation

I'm sure there is a really easy way of finding the answer to this question but I have no idea how to ask for what I want in this case. 
Basically my front page will be populated with images that relate to articles elsewhere on my site. There will also be three separate divs containing text displayed on top of those images.
How can I automatically extract certain elements from the articles and display them on the main page. 
Basically, how can I populate my front page with elements from my articles without doing it manually.
thankyou

Comment: It's not clear what's meant by "extract" here. Could you give an example?

Comment: This is exactly my problem. Im finding it really difficult to articulate exactly what I mean... Say I have an article about cats..
There is a headline at the top, a subtitle below and then an image of a cat below that...
How do I automatically populate a div on my main page to display the image of the cat, the title and the subtitle?

Comment: There are many ways to get external content into your page... Look for `iframes` or Ajax requests...

Comment: I dont think iframes are going to be able to give me what I need. If you look at the image links to the articles on Cracked.com, thats what I would like

Comment: It sounds like you need some kind of content management system, if I'm understanding what you're asking. This doesn't sound like some specific coding question in that case.

Answer (score 0):

**main page**

This is how I may create a simple image with text inside.
This is the manual option.

```
<div id="mainimage"><img src="mainimage.jpg">
<div id="header">header</div>
<div id="subtitle">subtitle</div>
<div id="author">author</div>
</div>
```

What I was envisaging doing was something like this:

```
<div id="mainimage"><img src="[code searches for specific image on another page]">
<div id="header">[code searches for header on another page]</div>
<div id="subtitle">[code searches for subtitle on another page]</div>
<div id="author">[code searches for author details on another page]</div>
</div>
```